# Automapper: How do you map a type that is conditional?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, automapper

Greeting Gurus,

So basically I have this a Map that I setup for use for TripFeeSchedule, trip fee schedule is a IEnumerable type. I am trying to map this so I do not have to have 5 or so ValueResolvers, and I am stuck.

What I basically want to do is map a type of OPtional fee from a single fee schedule. So for example if the type is a late fee I want to map that specific type with price and fee being retrieved and displayed aptly. Because these fees are not always there I am trying to make this as simple as possible.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Trip, TripManagementViewModelCreateEdit>().ForMember(dto => dto.TripOverride, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<TripCompResolver>().FromMember(x => x.TripComp))
.ForMember(dto => dto.BusOverride, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<TripCompResolver>().FromMember(x => x.TransportComp)).ForMember(dto => dto.RentalSki, opt => opt.MapFrom<TripFeeSchedule>(x=> x.ScheduledFees.First()) );
```

ScheduledFees dies on me, says Object Not Refrenced.

I have the map and it seems to be working (debugger shows that its being called)

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   AutoMapper.Mappers.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.MapPropertyValue(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper, Object mappedObject, PropertyMap propertyMap) +393
   AutoMapper.Mappers.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +309
   AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +221
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) +723

```
[AutoMapperMappingException: Trying to map FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.TripFeeSchedule to FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.ViewModels.OptionalFee.
Using mapping configuration for FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.TripFeeSchedule to FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.ViewModels.OptionalFee
Destination property: RentalSki
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.]
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) +811
   AutoMapper.Mappers.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.MapPropertyValue(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper, Object mappedObject, PropertyMap propertyMap) +601

[AutoMapperMappingException: Trying to map FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.TripFeeSchedule to FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.ViewModels.OptionalFee.
Using mapping configuration for FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.TripFeeSchedule to FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.ViewModels.OptionalFee
Destination property: RentalSki
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.]
   AutoMapper.Mappers.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.MapPropertyValue(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper, Object mappedObject, PropertyMap propertyMap) +699
   AutoMapper.Mappers.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +309
   AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +221
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) +723

[AutoMapperMappingException: Trying to map FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.Trip to FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.ViewModels.TripManagementViewModelCreateEdit.
Using mapping configuration for FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.Trip to FreeLivinEnertainment.Core.ViewModels.TripManagementViewModelCreateEdit
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.]
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) +811
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType) +132
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(TSource source) +150
   AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(TSource source) +117
   FreeLivinEnertainment.Web.Controllers.Admin.TripsController.ShowEditTrip(Int32 id) in D:\Projects\jimbo\app\FreeLivinEnertainment.Web.Controllers\Controllers\Admin\TripManagementController.cs:138
   lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a() +52
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +254
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +254
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +192
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +314
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +105
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +7
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8679150
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this, I feel like a moron, I guess I can just run the lambda on the From Member and then I can do what I need to get the result back.

`opt => opt.ResolveUsing().FromMember(x => x.ScheduledFees.First()`